# How to round of datetime Seconds to nearest zero?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, datetime, timestamp

i have a Dataframe which has datetime stamps.

| date | time |
| --- | --- |
| 2017-06-25 | 00:31:53 |
| 2017-06-25 | 00:32:36 |
| 2017-06-25 | 00:33:11 |
| 2017-06-25 | 00:33:59 |
| 2017-06-25 | 00:34:31 |
| 2017-06-25 | 00:35:17 |

I want to round off the seconds to nearest zeros if the
eg.

| date | time |
| --- | --- |
| 2017-06-25 | 00:31:50 |
| 2017-06-25 | 00:32:40 |
| 2017-06-25 | 00:33:10 |
| 2017-06-25 | 00:34:00 |
| 2017-06-25 | 00:34:30 |
| 2017-06-25 | 00:35:20 |

is there a way to do this in python ?

Comment: do you have one or two columns?

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Series.dt.round`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.round.html) with `10S` parameter:

```
df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['datetime'])
df['datetime'] = df['datetime'].dt.round('10S')
print (df)
             datetime
0 2017-06-25 00:31:50
1 2017-06-25 00:32:40
2 2017-06-25 00:33:10
3 2017-06-25 00:34:00
4 2017-06-25 00:34:30
5 2017-06-25 00:35:20
```

If 2 columns:

```
df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'] + ' ' + df['time'])
df['datetime'] = df['datetime'].dt.round('10S')

df['date'] = df['datetime'].dt.date
df['time'] = df['datetime'].dt.time
print (df)
         date      time            datetime
0  2017-06-25  00:31:50 2017-06-25 00:31:50
1  2017-06-25  00:32:40 2017-06-25 00:32:40
2  2017-06-25  00:33:10 2017-06-25 00:33:10
3  2017-06-25  00:34:00 2017-06-25 00:34:00
4  2017-06-25  00:34:30 2017-06-25 00:34:30
5  2017-06-25  00:35:20 2017-06-25 00:35:20
```

---

```
d = pd.to_datetime(df['date'] + ' ' + df['time']).dt.round('10S')

df['date'] = d.dt.date
df['time'] = d.dt.time
print (df)
         date      time
0  2017-06-25  00:31:50
1  2017-06-25  00:32:40
2  2017-06-25  00:33:10
3  2017-06-25  00:34:00
4  2017-06-25  00:34:30
5  2017-06-25  00:35:20
```